# Google Merchant Product Feed with Simple & Configurable product relationship

Tags: php, magento, google-shopping

I want to create feed for google shopping using Configurable & simple product relationship. Any body have any idea/sample xml file to how to crate configurable & simple products relationship feed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figure it out myself after doing some R & D. Basically we need to use item group id with all simple products and it should have sku of parent product so that google shopping knows that these products are variants not the duplicate copy of each other.

When naming your variant products, be sure to include the title common to all variant items

Please review the example below so that it can help other people also.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<rss version ='2.0' xmlns:g='http://base.google.com/ns/1.0'>
<channel>
<title><![CDATA[Website Title]]></title>
<description><![CDATA[Website Desctiption.]]></description>
<link>http://www.domain.com/</link>

    <item>
    <g:id>2450</g:id>
    <title><![CDATA[Product Title]]></title>
    <link>http://www.domain.com/product_url/</link>
    <g:price>70.00 USD</g:price>
    <g:sale_price>49.00 USD</g:sale_price>
    <description><![CDATA[Product Description.]]></description>
    <g:condition>new</g:condition>
    <g:expiration_date>2013-11-20</g:expiration_date>
    <g:image_link>http://www.domain.com/product_image_name.png</g:image_link>
    <g:brand><![CDATA[Product Brand]]></g:brand>
    <g:mpn><![CDATA[Product SKU]]></g:mpn>
    <g:product_type><![CDATA[Shoes]]></g:product_type>
    <g:google_product_category><![CDATA[Apparel & Accessories > Shoes]]></g:google_product_category>
    <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
    <g:size>6</g:size>
    <g:gender>Female</g:gender>
    <g:age_group>Adult</g:age_group>
    <g:color>BLUE</g:color>
    <g:item_group_id>Configurable Products Sku</g:item_group_id>
    </item>

    <item>
    <g:id>2450</g:id>
    <title><![CDATA[Product Title]]></title>
    <link>http://www.domain.com/product_url/</link>
    <g:price>70.00 USD</g:price>
    <g:sale_price>49.00 USD</g:sale_price>
    <description><![CDATA[Product Description.]]></description>
    <g:condition>new</g:condition>
    <g:expiration_date>2013-11-20</g:expiration_date>
    <g:image_link>http://www.domain.com/product_image_name.png</g:image_link>
    <g:brand><![CDATA[Product Brand]]></g:brand>
    <g:mpn><![CDATA[Product SKU]]></g:mpn>
    <g:product_type><![CDATA[Shoes]]></g:product_type>
    <g:google_product_category><![CDATA[Apparel & Accessories > Shoes]]></g:google_product_category>
    <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
    <g:size>7</g:size>
    <g:gender>Female</g:gender>
    <g:age_group>Adult</g:age_group>
    <g:color>BLUE</g:color>
    <g:item_group_id>Configurable Products Sku</g:item_group_id>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Do the two `<g:id>` values need to be different?

Comment: this solved part of the problem, but if you have simple products that are part of a configurable but also sold on its own there is still the duplicate id issue

Comment: @Ram-sharma, can you please inform us if this is accurate still in 2023? If I have a configurable product and simples, and the simple products are 'Not visible individually' (Magento 2); I only have one link. Shouldn't `g:id` be the simple product SKUs (different)?